# Edit FormCentral online and save to server

Tags: php, pdf, adobe

So my server loads in a pdf and shows it.
This pdf contains forms to fill in.
I want these forms editable in the browser(Currently I use an embed for the pdf) and then a button to save the pdf(To the webserver, not to the client!).

The reason I don't make an html form out of it is because there are 5 different pdf's to do this to and total of 60 pages of inputs to fill in

Any ideas on this?

EDIT: This is created with Adobe Forms Central

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.fillanypdf.com/) can help? Or any other service of this kind. The cost seems low enough for the trouble it saves.

Comment: Thanks a lot, though I really want something else. Not looking to spend money.

Comment: Btw, doesn't Adobe Forms Central use HTML? From the Adobe site:  _Adobe FormsCentral, an online forms service from Adobe that lets you easily distribute, collect and analyze data using HTML forms and surveys_

Comment: Tried, though the html exported can't be edited or anything :/ But might be a mistake on my side, will look into it more. Thanks for the tip though!